# Solr: how to get total number of results for grouped query using the Java API

Tags: solr, grouping

I have the following:

43 documents indexed in Solr

If I use the Java API to do a query without any grouping, such as:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*:*");
query.setRows(10);
```

I can then obtain the total number of matching elements like this:

```
solrServer.query(query).getResults().getNumFound(); //43 in this case
```

The `getResults()` method returns a `SolrDocumentList` instance which contains this value.

If however I use grouping, something like:

```
query.set("group", "true");
query.set("group.format", "simple");
query.set("group.field", "someField");
```

Then the above code for retrieving query results no loger works (throws NPE), and I have to instead use:

```
List<GroupCommand> groupCommands = solrServer.query(query).getGroupResponse().getValues();
List<Group> groups = groupCommand.getValues();
Group group = groups.get(groupIndex);
```

I don't understand how to use this part of the API to get the overall number of matching documents (the 43 from the non-grouping query above). First I thought that with grouping is no longer possible to get that, but I've noticed that if I do a similar query in the Solr admin console, with the same grouping and everything, it returns the exact same results as the Java API *and also* `numFound=43`. So obviously the code used for the console has some way to retrieve that value even when grouping is used:

[image]

My question is, how can I get that overall number of matching documents for a query using grouping executed via Solr Java API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In looking at the source for [Group](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_2/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/Group.java?view=markup) that is returned from your `groups.get(groupIndex)` call, it has a getResults() method that returns a [SolrDocumentList](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_2/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/common/SolrDocumentList.java?view=markup). The SolrDocumentList has a getNumFound() method that should return the overall number, I believe...

So you should be able to get this as the following:

```
  int numFound = group.getResults().getNumFound();
```

Hope this helps.

**Update:** I believe as OP stated, group.getResults().getNumFound() will only return the number of items in the group. However, on the [GroupCommand](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_2/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/GroupCommand.java?view=markup) there is a getMatches() method that may be the corresponding count that is desired.

```
 int matches = groupCommands.getMatches();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that's it. I can't check right now, but I think the SolrDocumentList instance inside a given Group instance returns info about what's in the group (i.e. if you limit groups' elements to x, getNumFound() will tell you how many total hits *in that group* you have, hence not overall total matches...

Comment: I believe you are right after looking more closely at the comments for the getResults method. Please see updated answer.

Comment: I'm gonna accept your answer because it's what I'm actually gonna use. This works for me as I use only one field to group, and I use "simple" group format resulting in having only one GroupCommand with only one Group in it at most. For this situation, either GroupCommand.getMatches or Group.getResults().getNumFound() return the overall number of matches. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 4):

If you set the ngroups parameter to true (default false) this will return the number of groups.

eg:

`solrQuery.set("group.ngroups", true);`

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping

this can then be retrieved from your responding GroupCommand with:

`int numGroups = tempGroup.getNGroups();`

At least that was my understanding?